# Data summary table does not work with tidyverse and stargazer() package

Tags: r, tidyverse, stargazer

I try to build a data summary table using the following format.
But outcome is quite not pretty, for example, `\$\textbackslash pm\$`, which is supposed to be `$\pm$` instead. I can hardly find any problem in my codes. Any suggestion, please?

```
library(stargazer)
library(qwraps2)
data("mtcars2")

our_summary1 <-
  list("Miles Per Gallon" =
       list("min"       = ~ min(mpg),
            "max"       = ~ max(mpg),
            "mean (sd)" = ~ qwraps2::mean_sd(mpg)),
       "Displacement" =
       list("min"       = ~ min(disp),
            "median"    = ~ median(disp),
            "max"       = ~ max(disp),
            "mean (sd)" = ~ qwraps2::mean_sd(disp)),
       "Weight (1000 lbs)" =
       list("min"       = ~ min(wt),
            "max"       = ~ max(wt),
            "mean (sd)" = ~ qwraps2::mean_sd(wt)),
       "Forward Gears" =
       list("Three" = ~ qwraps2::n_perc0(gear == 3),
            "Four"  = ~ qwraps2::n_perc0(gear == 4),
            "Five"  = ~ qwraps2::n_perc0(gear == 5))
       )

by_cyl2 <- summary_table(mtcars2, summaries = our_summary1, by = c("cyl_factor"))
stargazer(by_cyl2)
```

Result:

```
\begin{table}[!htbp] \centering 
  \caption{} 
  \label{} 
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}} cccc} 
\\[-1.8ex]\hline 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
 & 6 cylinders (N = 7) & 4 cylinders (N = 11) & 8 cylinders (N = 14) \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
min & 17.8 & 21.4 & 10.4 \\ 
max & 21.4 & 33.9 & 19.2 \\ 
mean..sd. & 19.74 \$\textbackslash pm\$ 1.45 & 26.66 \$\textbackslash pm\$ 4.51 & 15.10 \$\textbackslash pm\$ 2.56 \\ 
min.1 & 145 & 71.1 & 275.8 \\ 
median & 167.6 & 108 & 350.5 \\ 
max.1 & 258 & 146.7 & 472 \\ 
mean..sd..1 & 183.31 \$\textbackslash pm\$ 41.56 & 105.14 \$\textbackslash pm\$ 26.87 & 353.10 \$\textbackslash pm\$ 67.77 \\ 
min.2 & 2.62 & 1.513 & 3.17 \\ 
max.2 & 3.46 & 3.19 & 5.424 \\ 
mean..sd..2 & 3.12 \$\textbackslash pm\$ 0.36 & 2.29 \$\textbackslash pm\$ 0.57 & 4.00 \$\textbackslash pm\$ 0.76 \\ 
Three & 2 (29) & 1 (9) & 12 (86) \\ 
Four & 4 (57) & 8 (73) & 0 (0) \\ 
Five & 1 (14) & 2 (18) & 2 (14) \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}
```

Comment: The usual caveat: you shouldn’t use ‘stargazer’, because [‘stargazer’ is an utterly atrocious package](https://www.reddit.com/r/rstats/comments/6o9v9h/whats_your_favorite_relatively_obscure_r_package/dkgw9q1/). Use ‘[modelsummary](https://cran.r-project.org/package=modelsummary)’ or ‘[texreg](https://cran.r-project.org/package=texreg)’ instead, or *literally anything else*.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, `stargazer()` provides no way to allow LaTeX code in the labels in your table.  What you could do instead is to replace the latex `$\pm$` that was put there by `qwraps2` with something that `stargazer` will leave alone, run `stargazer`, then put back the LaTeX code.  For example,

```
hidepm <- function(s, replacement) 
  gsub("\\$\\\\pm\\$", replacement, s)

restorepm <- function(s, replacement)
  gsub(replacement, "$\\\\pm$", s)

stargazer2 <- function(x, replacement = "PlusMinus", ...) 
  restorepm(stargazer(hidepm(x, replacement = replacement), ...),
            replacement = replacement)

stargazer2(by_cyl2)
```

If you happen to have the string "PlusMinus" in your table (or it causes some other problem), use a different replacement.

Answer (score 0):

I get this output from `qwraps2::mean_sd()` function. Latex ignores the forward-slash which is likely the issue. Perhaps use another library to calculate standard-deviation?

"15.40 $\pm$ 5.29"

Answer (score 0):

Other packages generate a relatively same output:

**Xtable:**

```
library(xtable)
xtable(by_cyl2)
```

**F.e.:**

```
mean..sd..1 & 183.31 \$$\backslash$pm\$ 41.56 & 105.14 \$$\backslash$pm\$ 26.87 & 353.10 \$$\backslash$pm\$ 67.77 \\
```

---

**kableExtra:**

```
library(kableExtra)
kable(by_cyl2, "latex")
```

**F.e.:**

```
mean (sd) & 183.31 \$\textbackslash{}pm\$ 41.56 & 105.14 \$\textbackslash{}pm\$ 26.87 & 353.10 \$\textbackslash{}pm\$ 67.77\\
```

If you aren't satisfied with this output - you can manually parse and change `\$\textbackslash pm\$` to `$\pm$`.